# Why i'm getting an empty list when i try to use find_all function to searching by css with "class_" in Python 3.8 using bs4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I wanna get all links which includes specific class. Therefore i am using this code:

```
def getProductList(data, pageLinks):
    content = BeautifulSoup(data.content, 'html.parser')
    a = content.find_all("a", class_="sresult lvresult clearfix li shic")
    print(a)
```

but im getting this output and i know that there are lots of links includes this class:

```
C:/Users/projects/getData.py
    []
```

I checked the [doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) and it should be true. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: should be class_= ?

Comment: Yeah.  It is an equal sign, not a colon. `class_="sresult lvresult clearfix li shic"`

Comment: Yes sorry, but this time my list is empty and i know that there are lots of links includes this class

Comment: Can you check the question again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the linked documentation it should be class_= not class_:

Comment: Please vote to close typographical errors, rather than posting an answer :)